# Docker registry getsockopt: connection refused

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, docker, docker-registry

I am attempting to set up my own docker registry on an EC2 instance, Ubuntu Server 16.04.  Having followed https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/, I currently have nginx running with LetsEncrypt and have successfully started the docker registry service with the `docker run` command.  However, the system responds that the connection is refused when doing `docker push`.

Below I have substituted my FQDN with docker.example.com but the DNS is resolving correctly.

```
$ docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name docker-registry -v /etc/letsencrypt/live/docker.example.com:/certs -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/fullchain.pem -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/privkey.pem registry:2
$ docker pull ubuntu
$ docker tag ubuntu docker.example.com:5000/ubuntu
$ docker push docker.example.com:5000/ubuntu
The push refers to a repository [docker.example.com:5000/ubuntu]
Get https://docker.example.com:5000/v1/_ping: dial tcp 54.x.x.x:5000: getsockopt: connection refused
```

The service appears to be listening.

```
$ sudo netstat -tlnp | grep :5000
tcp6    0     0 :::5000           :::*            LISTEN      9655/docker-proxy
```

And I can even connect on localhost.

```
$ nc -nv 127.0.0.1 5000
Connection to 127.0.0.1 5000 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
```

But attempting to connect remotely fails.

```
$ nc -nv 54.x.x.x 5000
nc: connect to 54.x.x.x port 5000 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

The firewall also allows 5000/tcp.

```
$ sudo ufw status | grep 5000
5000/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
5000/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

The AWS ACL allows 5000/tcp to everyone (0.0.0.0/0).  What am I missing?

Comment: the aws security group firewall

Comment: @PaulBecotte I have 5000/tcp open to everyone (0.0.0.0/0).  Is there a separate port that needs to be opened?

Comment: You mentioned the ACL.  I was pointing out that you also need to set the security group.  (If that is what you meant by ACL, then this isn't the issue) http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html

Comment: @PaulBecotte Gotcha.  That was the intended meaning, apologies for any misunderstanding with the terminology.